# Passing struct containing a predifined array from C# to C

Tags: c#, c, arrays, struct

I am trying to use a dll written in C in a C# program. I have defined a simple struct which contains an integer and an array. The array will not have always the same length. I have also written a simple code to better understand why it does not work.

The C# program initializes this struct and fills this array with data, then it passes to the dll. In order to check that this works correctly, the dll copies the content of the array of this struct to another array (initialized already in C#). Finally the C# program prints both arrays which should be the same, it is not case.

Execution shows no error, but it seems that the dll can not interpret correctly the content of the struct.
I tried to use some Marshal instructions but I am not so familiar with them, so it did not help. Here are both codes, C and C#, thank you very much for your help.

Thomas

---

```
    #THE C# CODE

    #region DeclareStruct
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct Test
    {
        public double[] theVector;
        public int nElements;    
    }
    #endregion DeclareStruct

    #region DLLFunctions
    [DllImport("TestLib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "readStruct")]
    public static extern void readStruct(ref Test theStruct, double[] a);
    #endregion DLLFunctions


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        //delcare struc
        Test myStruct = new Test();
        myStruct.nElements = 10;//will not be always 10
        myStruct.theVector = new double[myStruct.nElements];

        //fills myStruct.theVector
        for (int i = 0; i < myStruct.nElements; i++) myStruct.theVector[i] = i * i;

        //delcare the array a which should have the same content as  myStruct.theVector
        double[] a = new double[myStruct.nElements];

        // Initialize unmanged memory to hold the struct.
        //IntPtr pnt = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(myStruct)));
        //Marshal.StructureToPtr(myStruct, pnt, false);

        //executes dll
        readStruct(ref myStruct, a);

        //display myStruct.theVector and a
        Console.WriteLine("This is theVector");
        for (int i = 0; i < myStruct.nElements; i++) Console.WriteLine(myStruct.theVector[i].ToString());

        Console.WriteLine("This is a");
        for (int i = 0; i < myStruct.nElements; i++) Console.WriteLine(a[i].ToString());


    }
```

---

```
            #THE C CODE

    typedef struct Test
    {
        double* theVector;
        int nElements;
    }
    Test;


    __declspec (dllexport) void readStruct(Test *myTest, double *a)
    {       
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < myTest->nElements; i++) a[i] = myTest->theVector[i];
    }
```

Comment: Can you change the c/c++ source code?  If so its arguably easier to use c++/CLI than muck about with p-invoke

Comment: Did you try to declare concrete size of s `double` array you're passing? Like with something like ` [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 10)]` written on top `theVector` declaration in C# structure.

Comment: @tigran, it is not ByValArray, it is LPArray, pointer. And probably ArraySubType needed, to lazy to test :-)

Comment: @tigran I already considered to use something like [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 10)], the problem is that the size won't be always the same.

Comment: @vitalygolub, could you please detail a bit?

Comment: @Thomas i think, attribute should be [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPArray ,
            ArraySubType = System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.R8 )]
And even in this case, if you pass  null, you will get access violation in your C dll